# MySQL Permitir a un usuario crear y administar sus propias bases de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, centos

Estoy interesado en saber como puedo crear varios usuarios en un servidor local MySQL con **Centos 6**, el objetivo es que cada usuario pueda crear sus bases de **datos(no crearlas yo y darles los permisos) y administrarlas(crear tablas, consultas, etc)**, pero que no pueda mover ni mirar las base de datos de otros usuarios.

Gracias....

Comment: tienes que revsiar los permisos de los usarios a traves de la consola de mysql y darle los que corresponden segun tus requerimientos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que problema tuviste con esto?

Comment: @Jackson-Quintero ya no escribas "pequeña modificación" como resumen de la edición. Como su nombre lo dice, debe ser un _resumen_ de los cambios que hiciste. De hecho, las ediciones deben ser para mejorar o corregir una pregunta: hacer una edición solo para colocar en negritas ciertas expresiones, es innecesario.

Comment: @padaleiana  ok esta bien comprendo gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 0):

Accede a la cuenta de root:

```
# mysql -u root -p
```

Una vez en la consola de MySQL:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    
mysql> GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Sin embargo, esto solo crea el usuario y le da privilegios de creacion de bases de datos, pero puede ver y manipular la de otros usuarios.